# VS Code Debug PHP and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, visual-studio-code

I have exerpience with Visual Studio Pro.  Works flawlessly with C# and javascript.  Also works okay with PHP and javascript using plugin.

Want to separate IDEs.  So VS Pro for C#, VS Code for PHP.

With VS Code, the debugger works fine with PHP.  I cannot get it to stop (respect break points) in javascript.  I'm not using Node, which is what most Googling (Duck Duck Go) brings back.

Yes, the js code is in a separate file.  =)

Is it an extension, and or configuration?

Comment: If you don't use node, are we talking about JS code that runs in the browser? In that case that's the debugger you'll want to use (the browser's)

Comment: Wow, that sucks.  It's touted as working "out of the box" with Javascript.  I guess they just mean Node.  Thanks for the answers, and to be sure, I did look for an answer before posting.

Comment: VS Code is one of the best editors currently around, and debugging non-node JS inside an IDE/editor doesn't make *any* sense (since the entire browser environment which contains `window` and `document` simply isn't there). That's why *browsers* have a debugger.

Comment: I guess that's why it's supported in VS Pro?

Comment: "Consistency," Microsoft's middle name!

Comment: If VS Pro included a headless instance of internet explorer, then yes. VS Code is specifically created to be *lightweight* and fast.

Comment: I've never taken the time to try it out but major browsers support remote debugging nowadays (e.g. [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Remote_Debugging)). It's probably just a matter of having a VSCode extension that connects the dots—I understand that's what the linked question explains.

Comment: The link info helped me to get this working.  Just very disappointed that VS Code doesn't work "out of the box" with javascript as touted.  Not to mention that once it works it has issues intermittently.  I still prefer the built in, out of the box, functionality of VS Pro (albeit, it's not free).